# Find the maximum and minimum values of $x-\sin2x+\frac{1}{3}\sin 3x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Find the maximum and minimum values of $x-\sin2x+\frac{1}{3}\sin 3x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$.

---

Let $f(x)=x-\sin2x+\frac{1}{3}\sin 3x$
$f'(x)=1-2\cos2x+\cos3x$
Put $f'(x)=0$
$1-2\cos2x+\cos3x=0$ gives $2\sin^2x-\cos2x+\cos3x=0$
I am stuck here.I cannot find the critical values and the maximum and minimum values of the function.Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$f'(x)=1-2(2\cos^2x-1)+4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$$
$$=4\cos^3 x-4\cos^2 x-3\cos x+3$$

For $f'(x)=0$,
$\cos x=1$  is a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from $1-2\cos 2x+\cos 3x=0$:

$1-2\cos 2x+\cos 3x=0$

$1-2\left(2\cos ^2x-1\right)+\cos \left(x+2x\right)=0$

$1-2\left(2\cos ^2x-1\right)+\cos  x\cos 2x-\sin  x\sin 2x=0$

$1-2\left(2\cos ^2x-1\right)+\cos  x\left(2\cos ^2x-1\right)-\sin  x\left(2\sin  x\cos  x\right)=0$

$1-2\left(2\cos ^2x-1\right)+\cos  x\left(2\cos ^2x-1\right)-2\sin ^2x\cos  x=0$

$1-2\left(2\cos ^2x-1\right)+\cos  x\left(2\cos ^2x-1\right)-2\left(1-\cos ^2x\right)\cos  x=0$

$1-4\cos ^2x+2+2\cos ^3x-\cos x-2\cos  x+2\cos ^3x=0$

$4\cos ^3x-4\cos ^2x-3\cos  x+3=0$

$4\cos ^2x\left(\cos  x-1\right)-3\left(\cos  x-1\right)=0$

$\left(4\cos ^2x-3\right)\left(\cos  x-1\right)=0$

$\left(\cos ^2x-\frac34\right)\left(\cos  x-1\right)=0$

$\left(\cos  x-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\left(\cos  x+\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\left(\cos  x-1\right)=0$

$\cos  x=\frac{\sqrt3}2$ or $-\frac{\sqrt3}2$ or $1$.